# css class styles not applied

Tags: html, css

I've some code like this:

```
<div class="divleft">
<TABLE class="form-table">
    <TR  class="heading">
    <TD colspan="2" align="left">
        <h3>Account description</h3>
    </td>
    </tr>

          <TR>
       <TD>Name</TD>
       <TD><input name="Naam" id="Naam" type="text" class="InputText"  /></TD>
          </TR>
```

and a CSS style on the class heading like this (for testing purposes, not actual styling)

```
.form-table tr.heading{
border-bottom-width: 10px;
border-bottom-color:black;
}
```

However, this style is being ignored. When I inspect the element with google chrome tools I cannot see any other stylesheet element that could affect this.

Any ideas on what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 6):

border-style is missing

```
.heading{
border-bottom-width: 10px; border-style:solid;
border-bottom-color:black;
}​
```

You can write in single line like this

```
.heading{
    border-bottom: 10px solid black;
    }​
```